# Amazon Personalize - how to delete Batch Inference Job "Create in progres"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-personalize

I started with Amazon Personalize yesterday with the help of [this tutorial](https://github.com/dalacan/personalize-batch-recommendations). Since it took more time than expected, in the middle of the notebook I decided to postpone it and deleted all resources (Cloud Formation stack, Jupyter notebook, S3 Bucket). Evidently, something went wrong. I still have a Dataset Group with status 'Active'.
I cannot delete it, because there is one Batch Inference job with status 'Create in progress'. It has this status since yesterday, now for more than 12 hours.

How can I delete all of this? What charges should I expect?

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to stop 'Create in progress' for any of the Personalize resources. This is the downside of having 'black box' service.

I believe the best option would be to contact AWS Support team and they should be able to terminate it manually.

I had some cases, when some of resources creation were taking more than 12 hours and the time depends mostly on dataset size and type of the job. There is no other option than waiting for it to complete, if you don't want to contact the support.